# Does CodeIgniter validation class prevent SQL injection?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, validation

Science, I am validating my post data before inserting into database, assume it is safe from unwanted SQL-injection.  Or it is still vulnerable to attack? Do I need farther steps to clean up data?

These are the steps I took to insert data from user:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'location', 'trim|xss_clean');
After Pass Validation: $this->input->post('location')
Then Save into DB: $this->db->insert ('user', $data );
```

Also use CI xss_clean and ACL libs.
Question is it a safe practice?

Comment: Not sure for `form_validation` class but `Active Record` does if you use it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, CI valids your app, but you have to enable it in config.

application/config/config.php line 350:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

If you set this var to TRUE, all get, post and cookies will be filtered.

If you have enabled this option, you don't have to use:

```
**xss_clean**
```

in:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'location', 'trim|xss_clean');
```

Comment: Thanks for Global implementation tips.

Answer (score 0):

you can also enable codeigniter XSS filtering per form field by adding TRUE

```
$this->input->post('location', TRUE) ;
```